# How to use Serilog with Raygun and Autofac differentiating between logs and errors

Tags: autofac, serilog, raygun.io

I'm trying to use Serilog with the Raygun sink using AutoFac

I successfully configure Serilog with AutoFact using https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/serilog/R23B8CLso9Q

If I want to log a **trace/debug/info** to a log rolling file ONLY and **warning/error/fatal** to a rolling file and raygun

How can I configure the log?

This is my actual conf:

```
public static ILogger CreateLogger()
        {
            var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .ReadAppSettings();

            InitialiseGlobalContext(config);

            return config.CreateLogger();
        }
```

with the this web.config entries:

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.path" value="D:\WebRole\Logs\file-{Date}.txt" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.fileSizeLimitBytes" value="1024" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp} [{Level}] [{MachineName},{ApplicationName},{RuntimeVersion}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
```

Since the conf is global, if I add .WriteTo.Raygun(), It will log **trace/debug/info** to raygun I dont want that.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an additional config entry to limit events via the Raygun sink:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:Raygun.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Warning" />
```

You will also need to ensure the Raygun assembly is in the project's build output directory, and referenced with a "using" entry like:

```
<add key="serilog:using" value="Serilog.Sinks.Raygun" />
```

Comment: I added the following entries `<add key="serilog:write-to:Raygun.applicationKey" value="mykey" />`
    `<add key="serilog:write-to:Raygun.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Warning" />`, It does not log anything to Raygun. I'm using the following  pkgs versions `"Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Signed" version="4.2.1" "Serilog" version="1.4.168" "Serilog.Extras.AppSettings" version="1.4.168" "Serilog.Extras.Web" version="1.4.168" "Serilog.Sinks.Raygun" version="1.4.168"` do I need Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Mvc as it is a MVC site? what I'm missing here

Comment: You probably need `serilog:using` as described here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings#using-sink-extensions-from-additional-assemblies - edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this (like me) the answer is how @NicholasBlumhardt described. I however also made a mistake of not having the applicationKey immediately after the using

```
<add key="serilog:using:Raygun" value="Serilog.Sinks.Raygun" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Raygun.applicationKey" value="MYRAYGUNAPPLICATIONKEY" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Raygun.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Information" />
```